# Не получается локально подключиться к серверу Spring Boot c компьютера находяшегося в локальной сети

Tags: java, ubuntu, spring-boot

У меня написано серверное приложение Spring Boot. Однако я не могу обратиться к нему локально с другого компьютера в локальной сети. Оба устройства на Ubuntu.

Компьютер,на котором установлено приложение, успешно пингуется с помощью ping.

В application.yml установлены следующие настройки.
spring:
server:
address: 192.168.31.70
port: 8080

Так же пользовался утилитой ufw.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открывал порты и разрешал подключение нужного устройства. Не работает.